# Does FreeNAS support Windows 7 and OS X Time Machine?

Tags: windows-7, macos, nas, freenas

I'm thinking about installing FreeNAS on a box I have that's just collecting dust (or doing a sff build). I have both OS X and Windows 7 machines on my home network.

Does FreeNAS allow you to use both Time Machine and backup Windows 7 machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I last looked (about a year ago), it only supported Time Machine via a lot of hard work - mainly on the side of the Mac in order to tell it to use the Freenas box as a target. Freenas supports AFP and if things have improved in OSX in this regard, it should work fine.

For Windows, once you have set up Samba shares, it just works and works very well. Only warning I would give is that if you are storing images on it, make sure you have the drivers for your network card slipstreamed in to a restore disk as I have had problems restoring images I created on to some machines from across the network!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has become a lot easier with newer builds of FreeNAS; no defaults hacking on the Mac, just choose an option from a dropdown on FreeNAS:

> http://www.claytonstechnobabble.com/2011/08/moving-itunes-to-freenas.html